# Date time columns falls between two time ranges

Tags: excel, excel-formula, logic

To me it looks like more on logical. Here I need to put conditions on both the columns which are in Date time format. I can use helper column.

I have two columns like Dep time and Arr time in Date Time format ( 4/3/2016  10:30:00 AM).

```
if Dep time and arrival time falls between ( 0600-2159)
       diff b/w ( Dep time and Arr time) /2" 
if Dep time and arrival time falls between ( 2200-0559)  
       diff b/w ( Dep time and Arr time)/1.75
```

This works if Dep time and arrival time in same date.

```
=IF(AND(DT>V27,AT<V28),(M2-L2)/2 # Where V27 is 0600 and V28 2159
```

But if they are in different days, for example dept time is 04/03/2016 04:00:00 AM and Arrival time is 04/05/2016 07:00:00 AM, so I need to calculate that how much time it was in 0600-2159 time window and this 2200-0559 for these days of complete journey.

Appreciate your time! Here is the sample data print screen.

[image: Here is the print screen of sample data]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the hours between 0600-2159 I would use

```
=(MAX(MOD(A2,1),TIME(22,0,0))-MAX(MOD(A2,1),TIME(6,0,0)))+
(INT(B2)-INT(A2))*(16/24)+
(MAX(MOD(B2,1),TIME(6,0,0))-MAX(MOD(B2,1),TIME(22,0,0)))
```

First line considers the departure time, second line considers the numbers of days between dep and arrival and last line deals with arrival time.

the mod function returns you decimal portion of the date/time which is just your time.

The int function will return just the date (no time).

For the other catagory I would just use

=B1-A1-C1

(total time - 0600 to 2159 time)

Comment: Added the pic with sample data.

Comment: Modifed it. Please see if it makes sense. So yes the travel can be more than 24 hours.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to understand your calculation and validate with the sample data. Any quicky to convert the decimals back to hh:mm:ss format. Thank you very much for time!

Comment: format the cell as `[hh]:mm:ss`.  This will allow hours above 24 to be shown.

Comment: Nice answer. I would have been coming at it with the perhaps more traditional min(endtime1,endtime2)-max(startime1,starttime2) for the first and last days but it wouldn't have been such a neat formula. I might have tweaked yours slightly by noting that the third line is always <=0 so put a minus sign in front of it and make it the same as the first line except B2 instead of A2.

Comment: @gtwebb  Does division work in similar way as numbers. for example I got the 30:00:00 ( hh:mm:ss) in A1 and B1 is 2:15:00 ( hh:mm:ss) what will be in A1/B1 ( hh:mm:ss)

Comment: Dividing times just gives you a ratio so it wouldn't really be a time (hh:mm:ss) although Excel would let you format it like that.  30:00:00 is actually just 1.25 (days) 2:15:00 is just 0.09 (days).  Dividing gives you 13.33 (unitless) if you were to format it into hh:mm:ss it would give you 320:00:00 which is likely not useful.

Comment: Yes! that's what  I was surprised.